# find records with matching values in a column

Tags: sql

I want to return all the records that having matching phoneBoxRecordIDs in phoneBox DB.

```
SELECT * FROM phoneBox where phoneBoxRecordIDs MATCH
```

would return:

```
Id phoneBoxRecordIDs colour
4  492948            Blue
9  492948            Brown
27 492948            Pink
```

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Tag with the database you are really using.  Also, match to what?

Comment: The match is wrong, its an example of what I want to do but am unsure how to do it I want to return all the records in the phoneBox table where any values stored in phoneBoxRecordIDs column match any other values stored in the same column

Comment: Sounds like you'd have to use a nested select statement in the WHERE clause.

Comment: please supply all the tables required. the OP is incomplete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group by the field where count > 1,
But this would only return the phoneboxrecordid and the # of records with that id

`SELECT Count(*) [Count]
     , phoneBoxRecordIDs
  FROM phoneBox
Group By phoneBoxRecordIDs
Having Count(*) > 1`

Comment: you have to explicitly declare the joins... primitive style will soon deprecate

Answer (score 0):

If you want the rows where `phoneBoxRecordIDs` appear more than once, then an ANSI-standard method uses window functions:

```
select pb.*
from (select pb.*, count(*) over (partition by phoneBoxRecordIDs) as cnt
      from phoneBox
     ) pb
where cnt > 1
order by phoneBoxRecordIDs;
```

You could also do this by returning records only when a matching record exists:

```
select pb.*
from phoneBox pb
where exists (select 1
              from phoneBox pb2
              where pb2.phoneBoxRecordIDs = pb.phoneBoxRecordIDs and
                    pb2.id <> pb.id
             );
```